# Helicopter blades

Tags: optics, visible-light, speed

Why do the propellers on helicopter appear to be so slow when the propellers is going at full speed? Can you please explain this particular optical illusion to me?

Comment: Do you mean on TV or film? If so it's a [stroboscopic effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroboscopic_effect)

Comment: More Phys.SE posts on stroboscopic: http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=stroboscopic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to stroboscopic effect.

You often and easy see this in Films where you have a sharp frame rate.

But also our eyes and our brain has a limited frame rate:

http://movieline.com/2012/12/14/hobbit-high-frame-rate-science-48-frames-per-second/
http://www.skeptiko.com/stuart-hameroff-on-quantum-consciousness-and-singularity/

Since the frame-rate is not the same over the whole viewing-angle of the eyes, it can depend on how you look at the propellers if you see it or not... And since your eye has a certain response time the stroboscopic effect is not that "sharp".